# How to convert multiple text files to one excel file with a one cell space between file contents in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, visual-studio, text

**Don't be deterred by the wall of text!!! Question itself isn't too complex, my issue just requires a lot of context**
I have multiple excel files with text, and I have two versions of each file, with one having revisions being made to it. What I have currently is a program which compiles all the differences of one pair of files into one file, and then a program which writes those revisions in an excel file.
Ex:

```
file 1 (v1)
1
2
3
4

file 1 (v2)
2
1
3
4

program which compiles differences:
line 1: 1
line 2: 2

program which converts revisions as excel
line 1: 1 (in cell A1)
line 2: 2 (in cell A2)
```

what I'd like is a program which takes all the different pairs of files and outputs an excel with the revisions separated by a one cell space (denoting the different pairs of files), ideally one which consolidates my two programs below.

for example if along with the v1 and v2 of file 1 above, I input file 2:

```
file 2 (v1)
5
6
7
8

file 2 (v2)
5
7
6
8
```

what I'd like outputted would be

```
line 1: 1 (in cell A1)
line 2: 2 (in cell A2)

line 2: 6 (in cell A4)
line 3: 7 (in cell A5)
```

Here is my code:

```
   internal class Program
{

    private static void AddDataFromFile(_Worksheet excellWorkSheet, string fileName)
    {
        fileName = @"C: \Users\result2.txt";
        if (excellWorkSheet == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("excellWorkSheet");
        }

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("result2.txt");
        var rowCounter = 1;
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            var columnCounter = 1;
            var values = line.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                excellWorkSheet.Cells[rowCounter, columnCounter] = value;
                columnCounter++;
            }

            rowCounter++;
        }
    }

    private static void CloseQuitAndRelease(
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excellApp, Worksheet excellWorkSheet, Workbook excellWorkBook, object misValue)
    {
        excellWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        excellApp.Quit();
        ReleaseObject(excellApp);
        ReleaseObject(excellWorkBook);
        ReleaseObject(excellWorkSheet);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args" />
    /// The args. 
    /// 
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        var excellApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        var excellWorkBook = excellApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        var excellWorkSheet = (Worksheet)excellWorkBook.Sheets["Sheet1"];


        /* Data(excellWorkSheet); */
        const string InputfileName = "result2.txt";
        AddDataFromFile(excellWorkSheet, InputfileName);
        Safe(misValue, excellWorkBook, "result-informations.xls");

        CloseQuitAndRelease(excellApp, excellWorkSheet, excellWorkBook, misValue);

        Console.WriteLine("File created !");
    }

    private static void ReleaseObject(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to release the Object " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }

    private static void Safe(object misValue, Workbook excellWorkBook, string excellfilename)
    {
        excellWorkBook.SaveAs(
            excellfilename,
            XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal,
            misValue,
            misValue,
            misValue,
            misValue,
            XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive,
            misValue,
            misValue,
            misValue,
            misValue,
            misValue);
    }
```

and my code which compiles the differences to 1 text file:

```
private void button_compare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String directory = @"C:\";
        String[] linesA = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "test1.txt"));
        String[] linesB = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "test2.txt"));


        List<string> onlyB = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < linesA.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!linesA[i].Equals(linesB[i]))
            {
                onlyB.Add("line " + i + ": " + string.Join(" ", linesB[i].Split(' ').Except(linesA[i].Split(' '))));
            }
        }
        onlyB.Add("line " + linesB.Length + ": " + linesB.Last());
        File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "Result2.txt"), onlyB);

    }
```

Comment: You could try using OpenXml to create the excel file here's a [tutorial](http://www.dispatchertimer.com/tutorial/how-to-create-an-excel-file-in-net-using-openxml-part-2-export-a-collection-to-spreadsheet/) on it

Comment: What is not working in your code? Where is the problem/error etc?

Comment: @dee, it's not that there's an error, I'm wondering how to adjust the code to satisfy my query

Comment: In this case it would be better to post this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) then here.